# Deserialize varbinary column in SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, clr, binaryformatter

I have done a CLR table valued function to read data form .dat files. In `DataBin` column I serialized measured values and save it as a `varbinary` data type in SQL Server. There I saved the time column with each other measured values.

[image: result of my CLR table valued function]

Now I want to serialize this column and save this measured values into a table that looks like this below and save each time value with each other measured value

[image]

Should I do a function in C# for this? How will this look like?

Comment: These pictures don't really explain what you want to do.  What columns are going to these 3 columns you show.  How is the data transformed.  What exactly are you doing... give example input AND output.   And really... we are going to spend the time to write an answer, spend the time to type in the requirements -- DON'T POST SCREEN SHOTS THAT ARE TANGENTIAL TO THE PROBLEM.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write a C# function to parse data from binary column then insert back to new table.

1. Convert data from binary data object field to string
2. Using Regex to separate data for each field
3. Insert data from Regex result back to table database